# How to break a byte into 4 pairs of 2 bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I wonder how can I break a byte in 4 pairs of two bits.

E.g. I am given the following:

```
0xf0;    /* 11110000 */
```

and the output should be:

```
11
11
00
00
```

Answer (score 4):

you should check out the bitwise operations. They provide everything you need.

bitwise & for masking

```
0xf0 & 0b11000000 = 0b11000000
```

bit shift >>

```
0b11000000 >> 6 = 0b00000011
```

edit:

```
0b00000011 = (0xf0 & 0b11000000) >> 6;
0b00000011 = (0xf0 & 0b00110000) >> 4;
0b00000000 = (0xf0 & 0b00001100) >> 2;
0b00000000 = 0xf0 & 0b00000011;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void printBits(int byte)
{
  printf("%d%d\n",byte>>7,(byte>>6)&1);
  printf("%d%d\n",(byte>>5)&1,(byte>>4)&1);
  printf("%d%d\n",(byte>>3)&1,(byte>>2)&1);
  printf("%d%d\n",(byte>>1)&1,byte&1);
}
```